# Miller Rabin Test Slow Python

Tags: python

So, I read the pseudocode from http://www.javascripter.net/math/primes/miller_rabin_pseudocode.txt, and thought it would be cool to write it in python. So I wrote this:

```
n = input('Enter a number to test ')
n = int(n)
a=int(5)
d = n - 1
s = 0
while (d % 2 == 0):
   s = s + 1
   d = int(d/2)
x = a**d
x = x % n
if (x==1 or x==(n-1)):
   print("probably prime")
r = int(1)
while(r<(s-1)):
   x = x**2
   x = x%n
   if (x==1):
      print ("composite")
   if (x==(n-1)):
      print ("probably prime")
print("if nothing above is printed n is composite")
```

It worked pretty well, but as soon as I got into six digit numbers it was incredibly slow. So I found some code of http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#Python, and it was almost instant, even with large (10^30) numbers.

So, what did I do wrong int the above code that made it so much slower?

Comment: Why would you write `r = int(1)`? `1` is already an int; you don't need to call `int` on it.

Comment: @user2357112 bad habbit :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also replace:

```
x = a**d
x = x % n
```

With:

```
x = pow(a, d, n)
```

Which does modular exponentiation much faster than the naive method, as it takes modulus at each multiply, rather than building a ginormous number and taking modulus after.

Comment: This could probably be a comment.

Answer (score 3):

The second loop in the linked code does only 5 iterations at maximum, whereas your does something like log(n).

EDIT:
Or even more - the "r" variable is never modified, so the loop's exit condition will never be satisfied. The only possibility to exit the loop are the breaks.

Comment: My mistake! I forgot to add r = r+1 during the loop. I feel so stupid